# Can I SELECT *, COUNT(*) in the same query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of visits

```
ssn,eno,date
302609074,101,20180215
302609074,102,20181010
302609074,105,20190505
302609074,105,20190506
997600970,103,20190115
997600970,105,20190415
997600970,104,20181212
997600970,104,20181213
874136439,102,20190808
874136439,102,20190910
874136439,102,20191001
874136439,102,20191002
```

and a table of outcomes

```
ssn,date,scode,dcode,ppay,ipay
302609074,20180215,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20180215,4006,1003,40,100
302609074,20181010,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20181010,4006,1003,40,100
302609074,20190505,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20190506,4006,1003,40,100
997600970,20190115,4001,1002,25,50
997600970,20190115,4001,1003,40,30
997600970,20190115,4004,1004,40,50
997600970,20190415,4002,1004,40,95
997600970,20190415,4003,1005,40,100
997600970,20181212,4004,1001,25,47
997600970,20181213,4004,1001,25,47
874136439,20190808,4002,1002,25,50
874136439,20190808,4002,1003,40,60
874136439,20190910,4002,1004,40,95
874136439,20190910,4002,1005,60,90
874136439,20191001,4003,1002,25,50
874136439,20191002,4003,1002,25,50
```

I need to get the total number of visits in a certain date range, and I need to join visits and outcomes to get (for example) the sum of ipay for outcomes on the same dates.

I got my query like this:

```
SELECT X.NumberOfVisits, SUM(Y.ipay) TotalIPay
FROM (  
        (SELECT *, COUNT(*) NumberOfVisits
         FROM visit
         WHERE (vdate >=20190101 AND vdate <=20190331)
        ) X
        JOIN
        (SELECT *
         FROM outcome
        ) Y
        ON (X.vdate = Y.vdate)
    );
```

And it does not work.

If I split the query in to separate queries:

```
SELECT X.OverallNumberOfVisits
FROM (  
        (SELECT COUNT(*) OverallNumberOfVisits
         FROM visit
         WHERE (vdate >=20190101 AND vdate <=20190331)
        ) X
     );
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(Y.ipay) TotalIPay
FROM (  
        (SELECT *
         FROM visit
         WHERE (vdate >=20190101 AND vdate <=20190331)
        ) X
        JOIN
        (SELECT *
         FROM outcome
        ) Y
        ON (X.vdate = Y.vdate)
    );
```

Then that works.  But I don't want to do so.  I want to do it in a single query.  How do I combine them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Your queries seem way too complicated -- too many subqueries.  If you have a visit id (that is, a primary key on the table), you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.visit_id), SUM(o.ipay) TotalIPay
FROM visit v LEFT JOIN
     outcome o
     ON v.vdate = o.vdate
WHERE v.vdate >= 20190101 AND v.vdate <= 20190331;
```

I suspect that you actually want to join on both the `ssn` and `vdate`, but you say that your version works.

If you don't have a primary key, you can do:

```
SELECT MAX(num_visits), SUM(o.ipay) TotalIPay
FROM (SELECT v.*, COUNT(*) OVER () as num_visits
      FROM visit v
      WHERE v.vdate >= 20190101 AND v.vdate <= 20190331
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     outcome o
     ON v.vdate = o.vdate;
```